# How to convert a table into a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

If, for some reason, a base R (two dimensional) `table` object comes along in your R workflow, what is the best (concise, readable, efficient) way to convert it to a `data.table` while keeping its dimension structure?

*Example data*:

```
set.seed(1)
tab <- structure(
  sample(0:1, size = 15, replace = TRUE), 
  .Dim = c(5,3), 
  .Dimnames = list(
    Pr = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P9"), 
    Tr = c("T1", "T2", "T3")
  ), 
  class = "table"
)
```

*Example of failed attempts*

```
setDT(tab)
# Error in setDT(tab) : 
#   Argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'
as.data.table(tab) # same data.table(tab), *could* be fixed with dcast()
#     Pr Tr N
#  1: P1 T1 0
#  2: P2 T1 0
#  3: P3 T1 1
#  4: P4 T1 1
#  5: P9 T1 0
#  6: P1 T2 1
#  7: P2 T2 1
#  8: P3 T2 1
#  9: P4 T2 1
# 10: P9 T2 0
# 11: P1 T3 0
# 12: P2 T3 0
# 13: P3 T3 1
# 14: P4 T3 0
# 15: P9 T3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions are using `unclass` (converting the table into a regular 2d array) or the matrix method of `as.data.frame`:

```
# Convert it to a regular array with unclass
data.table(unclass(tab), keep.rownames = "Pr")
#    Pr T1 T2 T3
# 1: P1  0  1  0
# 2: P2  0  1  0
# 3: P3  1  1  1
# 4: P4  1  1  0
# 5: P9  0  0  1

# Convert it first to a data.frame 
setDT(as.data.frame.matrix(tab), keep.rownames = "Pr")[]
#    Pr T1 T2 T3
# 1: P1  0  1  0
# 2: P2  0  1  0
# 3: P3  1  1  1
# 4: P4  1  1  0
# 5: P9  0  0  1
```